# how to get dynamic location for Application.GetSaveAsFilename VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, filepath

I have code below to save my workbook file as WriteResPassword, but is there any way to get current workbook's path in the interface from
Application.GetSaveAsFilename? For now saving as interface displays document folder, so it requires 5-10 more clicks to get where I wanted.

```
    Sub PasswordSave()
       Application.DisplayAlerts = False
       Application.ScreenUpdating = False
       SaveAsName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
       ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SaveAsName, FileFormat:= xlNormal, WriteResPassword:="test", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
    End Sub
```

Comment: your question is unclear. did you research on the web about how to get workbook's full path ?

Answer (score 1):

The dialog's starting directory is whatever `CurDir` says it is, so you can use `ChDir` before calling the dialog:

```
ChDir Activeworkbook.Path
```

or

```
ChDir "C:\Users\Public\Desktop"
```

Answer (score 0):

`Activeworkbook.Path` will give you a string with the folder location of the workbook.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-path-property-excel

Comment: That's great, but doesn't answer OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

this opens at c:\windows

```
Application.GetSaveAsFilename "c:\windows"
```

so this is your answer

```
Application.GetSaveAsFilename activeworkbook.path
```